# How to rewrite sum as convex combination

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-hulls

I am currently stuck when trying to show a seemingly trivial equation.

Let $X$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m:\left\{1,2,\ldots n\right\}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}.$

For $i = 1,2,\ldots n$ and $j\leq m(i)$ we have scalars $\lambda_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and vectors $x_{ij} \in X$.

I want to show that every $x:=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m(i)}\lambda_{ij}x_{ij}$ can be written as

$$x = \sum_{j_1= 1}^{m(1)} \cdots \sum_{j_n= 1}^{m(n)} \mu_{j_{1}\cdots j_{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\sum_{j=1}^{m(i)} \lambda_{ij}) x_{ij_{i}}$$

with $\mu_{j_{1}\cdots j_{n}} \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $\sum_{}^{}\mu_{j_{1}\cdots j_{n}} = 1$.

I read this once and wondered how it is possible to chose such a convex combination. I tried everything but couldn't come up with a way to find those $\mu_{j_{1}\cdots j_{n}}$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It works with $$ \mu_{j_{1} \cdots j_{n}} := \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\lambda_{ij_{i}}}{\sum_{j=1}^{m(i)} \lambda_{ij}}. $$